# Threading.thread() creating thread inside a thread?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have below module:

```
def monitor(self):
    # Do something
    periodic_thread = threading.Timer(30, self.monitor)
    periodic_thread.start()
```

Does this mean, we are creating a thread within a thread every 30 seconds?
If I print current_thread, I have following results:

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 139936578074432)> 
 <_Timer(Thread-1, started 139936378812160)>
 <_Timer(Thread-2, started 139936370419456)>
 <_Timer(Thread-3, started 139936378812160)>
```

Comment: did you look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer) first?

Comment: Each monitor will create a new monitor every 30 seconds. This is a slow thread equivalent of a fork bomb.